# Rails3 and NginX CORS headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, cors

I have a Rails3 app hosted via NginX which provides a JSON API that shall support cross origin resource sharing (CORS). 
The related headers should be added via NginX, not via the Rails app.

Therefore I added a catcher in routes.rb to fetch OPTIONS preflight requests:

```
match "*options", controller: "application", action: "options", constraints: { method: "OPTIONS" }
```

and I added the corresponding endpoint to my application controller:

```
def options
  render :text => "", :layout => false
end
```

Works. Now I want a wide open CORS config for my NginX:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;
            passenger_enabled on;
            root /home/deployer/apps/fooapp/current/public;

            location /v1 {
                    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-FooApp-Auth-Token';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                            return 200;
                    }
                    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-FooApp-Auth-Token';
                    }
                    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-FooApp-Auth-Token';
                    }
            }
    }
```

Great, OPTIONS request have all the needed headers in the response now:

```
curl -i -H'Accept: application/json' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XOPTIONS 'http://api.fooapp.net/v1/api_session' -d'{"user":{"email":"demo@fooapp.net", "password":"somepassword"}}'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2012 11:04:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-FooApp-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
```

But a real POST requests for example now fails with a 404:

```
curl -i -H'Accept: application/json' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'http://api.fooapp.net/v1/api_session' -d'{"user":{"email":"demo@fooapp.net", "password":"somepassword"}}'

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2012 11:06:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And it has to, cause the NginX log says:

```
2012/09/02 13:06:19 [error] 2464#0: *3 open() "/home/deployer/apps/fooapp/current/public/v1/api_session" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /v1/api_session HTTP/1.1", host: "api.fooapp.net"
```

I am new to NginX, and I know thats a wide open as well as very lightweight configuration. I do not understand why NginX tries to route these requests via public, so that the underlying Rails app is not requested. How do I have to change the configuration, so that all my requests are passed to the app as before, but the CORS headers are added anyway?

Thx in advance

Felix

Answer (score 2):

This comes a little late but since I just ran into the same problem it might help somebody else.

You need to enable passenger inside the location block

```
location /{
     ...
     passenger_enabled on;
     ...
 }
```

I hope this helps.